# Debugging for type script stopped working in visual studio code

Tags: angular, typescript, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code 1.40.2 for an Angular project. Breakpoints were being hit prior, but seemed to have stopped working. When I hover over breakpoints now, they say 'Breakpoint set but not yet bound'. How do I fix this?

My launch.json is as below:

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [


    {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
        "url": "http://localhost:4200",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
]
```